# How to automatically enable php extensions in Homestead on vagrant up

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead, php-extension

Im using Laravel 5.3 in Homestead with Vagrant  1.8.7 running on VirtualBox.

I have need to enable some php extensions.

I know that I could ssh into the box and edit the php.ini to enable the extension but this seems like a very anti-vagrant way to do this.

I want to tell Vagrant to provision the box with specific php extensions enabled so that I can simply call `vagrant up --provision` and the box will be ready to go (kinda the point of vagrant right?)

So, **How can we automatically enable php extensions in Homestead on vagrant up?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some tinkering, the below is what I came up with. I make no assurances that this is the *right way to do it* only that, in my case, it seems to be working:

Find the `after.sh` that was generated when you [installed homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead). For me, on Mac El Capitain, the file is created at `~/.homestead/after.sh`, I imagine there is a `.bat` in a similar location on windows.

**Do not** make the mistake of editing `~/Homestead/src/stubs/after.sh`, thats the template file from the homestead installation, not your actual generated copy.

---

#### Edit `after.sh`

Add the below lines to `after.sh` (this is my whole file, only the first 5 comment lines were in the default file):

```
#!/bin/sh

# If you would like to do some extra provisioning you may
# add any commands you wish to this file and they will
# be run after the Homestead machine is provisioned.

# in the below --assume-yes is to avoid confirms [y/N]
# DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive is to avoid a big menu asking if it's ok to 
# overwrite the php.ini file, may make --assume-yes redundant, not sure

# run apt-get update first, without it I was getting errors not finding the extensions 
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get --assume-yes update

# load any extensions you like here 
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get --assume-yes install php-xdebug 
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get --assume-yes install php7.0-ldap # update to php7.2-ldap if using php 7.2 etc...

# enable xdebug via cli
sudo phpenmod -s cli xdebug

# restart php and nginx
sudo service php7.3-fpm restart && sudo service nginx restart
```

If you dont psychically know the exact name for the extension you need (I didnt) you can use `sudo apt-cache search php7-*` or similar to list the available ones

---

#### vagrant destroy

Now, if you have homestead up, in the terminal, `cd` to your Homestead dir, for me `cd ~/Homestead` and then run `vagrant destroy`

---

#### vagrant up

While inside `/Homestead` run `vagrant up --provision`

---

#### Check install

To check that the extensions installed correctly, while inside `/Homestead` run these two commands:

`vagrant ssh`

`php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());"`

My output (33 and 61 were added):

```
DoDSoftware:Homestead DOoDSoftware$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-22-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
vagrant@homestead:~$ php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());"
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => libxml
    [3] => openssl
    [4] => pcre
    [5] => zlib
    [6] => filter
    [7] => hash
    [8] => pcntl
    [9] => Reflection
    [10] => SPL
    [11] => session
    [12] => standard
    [13] => mysqlnd
    [14] => PDO
    [15] => xml
    [16] => apcu
    [17] => apc
    [18] => bcmath
    [19] => calendar
    [20] => ctype
    [21] => curl
    [22] => dom
    [23] => mbstring
    [24] => fileinfo
    [25] => ftp
    [26] => gd
    [27] => gettext
    [28] => iconv
    [29] => igbinary
    [30] => imap
    [31] => intl
    [32] => json
    [33] => ldap
    [34] => exif
    [35] => mcrypt
    [36] => msgpack
    [37] => mysqli
    [38] => pdo_mysql
    [39] => pdo_pgsql
    [40] => pdo_sqlite
    [41] => pgsql
    [42] => Phar
    [43] => posix
    [44] => readline
    [45] => shmop
    [46] => SimpleXML
    [47] => soap
    [48] => sockets
    [49] => sqlite3
    [50] => sysvmsg
    [51] => sysvsem
    [52] => sysvshm
    [53] => tokenizer
    [54] => wddx
    [55] => xmlreader
    [56] => xmlwriter
    [57] => xsl
    [58] => zip
    [59] => memcached
    [60] => blackfire
    [61] => Zend OPcache
    [62] => xdebug
)
```

---

Like I stated at the beginning, I cant say this is the right way, but it's working for me so far.

#### If anyone sees a flaw in this approach, feel free to tell me Im doing it all wrong :)

Comment: Great, thanks for this! The only thing I changed was use `vagrant reload --provision` instead of `destroy` and `up`, to avoid losing my databases.

Answer (score 1):

you should first log onto Homestead server using ssh (probably you know this already - "vagrant ssh").

then go to "/etc/php/7.0/fpm/"
there is also for cli on this location "/etc/php/7.0/cli/"
edit it with "sudo vi php.ini" (esc and :wq to save changes).

then you should restart nginx:

```sh
sudo nginx -s reload"
```

and after that, restart php-fpm:

```sh
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart"
```

If you are not sure if it is PHP 5.x or 7.x on your homestead, use

```sh
find / -name php.ini
```

to find php.ini—you will probably get 2 or 3 results.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Im aware of how to enable the extension manually. However, I dont want to have to do this every time I do `vagrant up`. I need to be able to automate adding the extension as part of the provisioning process so that it's all set up properly when doing `vagrant up --provision`

Answer (score 1):

In case there's still a need for this :

=> https://guides.wp-bullet.com/install-apcu-object-cache-for-php7-for-wordpress-ubuntu-16-04/

=> Run the 3 first commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0-apcu -y
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Or simply add to after.sh:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.x-apcu -y
```

Comment: While accurate, this kind of misses the mark. The original need was specifically to _automatically enable php extensions in Homestead on vagrant up_. while this is only manually installing the same.

Comment: True. I understood it as "Make it available when I launch the vagrant". Not as "Get it ready when installing".